# No such route when editing object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an object that I am trying to allow users to edit in my rails 4 app. The user has_one supp_form and I want them to be able to edit the information in the supp_form. The page is loading fine and the relationships are setup properly.

**The error**

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/businesses/3/supp_form/edit"
```

when I rake routes I see the following route:

```
edit_business_supp_form_path    GET /businesses/:business_id/supp_form/edit(.:format)   supp_forms#edit
GET /businesses/:business_id/supp_form(.:format)    supp_forms#show
PATCH   /businesses/:business_id/supp_form(.:format)    supp_forms#update
PUT /businesses/:business_id/supp_form(.:format)    supp_forms#update
```

**supp_forms_controller.rb**

```
class SuppFormsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def new
      @suppform = SuppForm.new(supp_form_params)
    end

    def create
      @suppform = SuppForm.create(supp_form_params)
    end

    def edit
      @user = User.current_user
      @suppform = @user.supp_form
    end 

    def update
      @user = current_user
      @suppform = SuppForm.update(supp_form_params)
    end 

    private

        def supp_form_params
          params.require(:supp_form).permit(:id, :business_id, :title, :first_name, 
            :last_name, :applicant_role, :work_phone_number)
        end
end
```

**View**

```
<%= form_for @user.supp_form, :url => edit_business_supp_form_path(@user.supp_form), :html => { :class => "sky-form", :id => "sky-form4" } do |supp_form| %>
  <%= supp_form.text_field :work_phone_number, :placeholder => "Your new phone number"  %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it tries to access the route using a PATCH request, that is used for updating. In your routes the `/businesses/:business_id/supp_form/edit` route is only specified for GET requests, thus the error.
This happens because the path you are using in the form points to the `edit` action (which is only responsible for showing the edit form) and should instead point to the `update` action. So the route you should be actually using in the is the `supp_form_path` that, in connection with the PATCH method, pushes the information to the update action, where the object is updated.

Comment: Yes this worked- raised the next issue in the update method the supp_forms_controller.rb. Thank you!